# Is it necessary to Load all datasets in SSRS Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have a webapplication in MVC framework having SSRS (.rdlc) Reports..

I have come to situation where i have to load a Singal Report (m_memlst.rdlc) Report from two different modules.

so i have created two different dataSets and added both datasets in to the `m_memlst.rdlc` report.
(1) Customer_DataSet
(2) Product_DataSet

but when i set a dataset into `ReportDataSource`  from Customer Moduel and load data into `Customer_DataSet`, it throws an error saying `Product_DataSet` is not assigned... and wise versa...

so is it necessary to load both datasets when i call a Report ? or is there any way where we can hide or unload a particular dataset ???

Thanks...

Comment: I've only used SSRS reports embedded into WinForms and WPF apps, but I believe it should be the same.  I don't think you have to set the `ReportDataSource` if the datasets are already built into your `.rdlc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Reporting Services will try and retrieve data for all Datasets in the report when the report is executed, so if you haven't assigned one of them then the report execution will fail. There is no way to make some Datasets optional, although you can modify your underlying queries with parameters so that they don't return any results if passed certain parameter values.